# Django custom form field incorrectly renders value

Tags: django, widget, field, render

I am trying to create a custom model field and widget for displaying a google maps api v3 map and click-selecting a point, and storing that.

The value in the database should be in this format: LAT,LONG,FORMATTED_ADDRESS_BY_GOOGLE_REVERSE_GEOCODER

Here's my fields.py:

```
from django.db import models

class LatLong(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.lat = kwargs.get('lat',0)
        self.long = kwargs.get('long',0)
        self.addr = kwargs.get('addr','')

class CoordField(models.Field):

    description = 'Coordinates field'
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'LatLong obj'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 255 
        super(CoordField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'varchar(%s)' % self.max_length

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return '%s,%s,%s' % (value.lat, value.long, value.addr)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, LatLong):
            return value

        try:
            x = value.split(',')
        except:
            return LatLong(lat=0,long=0,addr='')

        return LatLong(lat=x[0], long=x[1], addr=','.join(x[2:]))
```

And my widgets.py:

```
from django.forms import Widget, TextInput

from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from settings import GMAPS_API_KEY


class LatLongWidget(TextInput):

    class Media:
        css = { 
            'all':('testing.css',)
        }   
        js = ( 
            'resource/js/coord.js',
        )   

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        default_attrs = {}

        if attrs:
            default_attrs.update(attrs)

        super(LatLongWidget, self).__init__(default_attrs)

    def render(self, *args, **kwargs):
        output = super(LatLongWidget, self).render(*args, **kwargs)

        output += render_to_string('maps/coord.html',
                                    {'GMAPS_API_KEY':GMAPS_API_KEY,
                                     'latlong': args[1]})

        return mark_safe(output)
```

As i understand it the to_python() definition from the field should always return a python object and get_prep_value() should do the exact opposite.

As you can see from the screenshot below the output of the field on the form is not the 3 values separated by comma, but the string repr of the LatLong object returned by to_python().

This automatically happens in my widget when i call `output = super(LatLongWidget, self).render(*args, **kwargs)`

Screenshot: [image: http://imgur.com/qnuSu]

What am i missing here? Should i be implementing more functions? Have i done this completely wrong?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The string that appears on the form is the string representation of the LatLong object and not the 3 commas notation.

Comment: Question seems straightforward to me. No idea why you got downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified my widget render() method to check for the type of the value parameter passed and convert it into a LatLong object if needed as such:

```
def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    if not isinstance(value, LatLong):
        value = value.split(',')
        value = LatLong(lat=value[0], long=value[1], addr=value[2:])

    output = super(LatLongWidget, self).render(name, '%s,%s,%s' % (value.lat, value.long, value.addr), attrs)

    output += render_to_string('maps/coord.html',
                                {'GMAPS_API_KEY':GMAPS_API_KEY,
                                 'latlong': value,
                                 'id':attrs['id'],})

    return mark_safe(output)
```

That seems to have fixed my problem since the 'value' parameter passed into render() is either a unicode string (when submitting the form) or a LatLong object when displaying the form.